# State of DevOps question

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I need to ask a question about the State of DevOps report and the relationship between Google, [Puppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_%28software%29) and DORA.

Where is the recommended location for this question?

Comment: We have a sister site [devops.se], but I don't know if your question is on-topic or not. Try asking on their meta first.

Comment: Those kind of questions tend not to fly on any site of the network. They are so out there that the only way we've able to allow them is by creating a site dedicated solely to those.

Comment: What is "DORA"? Is it related to [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol)? What is "the State of DevOps report"? Can you add some context to your question? But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now.

Answer (score 8):

Probably reddit?

You're looking to facilitate a *discussion*, not get concrete answers.  Because DevOps is a rapidly evolving field, there's no one answer in time that would fit the model of Stack Exchange, so it's likely off-topic everywhere.

Comment: ok, thanks.  BTW, not really sure why this question was downvoted. I my mind, meta is the place to ask where to ask a question.